# Dropbox Cordova

Tags: авторизация, cordova, dropbox

Доброго времени суток. 
Уже несколько недель пытаюсь разобраться с тем, как присоединить dropbox к своему приложению. Создала приложение в дропбоксе, и цепляюсь к нему. 
При логировании вываливается окно где мне предлагают подтвердить возможности использования файлов. Я щёлкаю разрешить (в приложении в дропбоксе Development users увеличивается на 1), но это окошко не  пропадает и не закрывается, и аворизация дальше не идёт.
Скачала вот такой пример: https://github.com/donovan-graham/cordova_oauth. Ситуация точно такая же. Но в этом случае хорошо видно, что при авторизации не возникает ошибки, а просто всё застревает. (Но опять же, если до этого обнулить Development users, то при этом неудачном логировании, оно всё равно увеличивается на 1)

Comment: как понять - "застревает"?

Comment: у меня поставлены alert-ы на оба колбека: и на ошибку и на удачу. и ни один не срабатывает

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте приспособить под свои нужды данный пример:

https://github.com/dropbox/cordova-datastores-example